# Disable variable in eval

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to disable some variables for an eval?

```
var test = 'example';
eval('console.log(test)'); // here I would like test null
console.log(test); // here test should display 'example'
```

Comment: Please provide more context to your question. **No**, this is not generally possible in this particular way. However, there are probably any number of ways to achieve what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: What do you mean test null? So what should the result of eval be?

Comment: How would that be null?? That would be an error if it was not defined. How to do it? You would have to create an iframe with a blank HTML page and do the evaluation in there if you do not want to have any globals bleed over to the eval.

Comment: Why was the question closed? Even though more context would be helpful, what is asked is pretty clear IMO.

Comment: Voted to reopen since there is a valid question....

Comment: @FelixKling Personally I would have liked *additional details to highlight exactly what you need*. As per the close reason. Seems reasonable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706274/plv8-disable-execute-and-prepare-function-in-eval

Here is to understand why I ask such a weird question. If I do plv8=null; then I cannot use anymore the function provided by the pgsql extension plv8 until I restart pgSql server.

Comment: you must mean, besides evaluating inside a closure? `eval('(function(){var test = null; console.log(test); })()');`

Comment: @RGraham: I understand. I wish this close reason was a bit more fine-tuned and we had one specifically that asks for more information. Or maybe not, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your `eval` call inside an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and shadow outer variables with local variables:

```
function doSeomthing() {
    var test = 'example';
    (function() {
        var test = null;
        eval('console.log(test)');
    })();
    console.log(test);
}
```

The `eval` code will only have access to the IIFE's local `test`, not the `test` declared inside of `doSomething`.

**Note**, however, that global variables cannot be shadowed in this way, since they will be accessible as properties of `window` or `global`. You could shadow `window` (or `global`) and deny access to all global variables as properties of `window`.

Comment: Alternatively, if one wants to prevent access to all local variables (but not globals), one can use the `Function` constructor: `new Function(strToEval)()` or an indirect eval call: `(0, eval)(strToEval)`.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's what I need. I will try tomorrow on my server.